# PHP - Multidimensional array not getting stored properly

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a simple 2D array in PHP and it doesn't seem to work as described.
For instance, I tried the sample code from the w3schools.com site:

```
$cars = array
  (
  array("Volvo",100,96),
  array("BMW",60,59),
  array("Toyota",110,100)
  );
```

But when I call:

```
 echo "$cars[1][1]";
```

it outputs "Array[1]", not "60".    As far as I can tell, the only thing that's getting stored is the string "Array".   It doesn't matter how big or small the array is or what method I declare it in or whether it's string or integer, etc... it doesn't actually store the proper data in any sort of array format.

Comment: Works for me - [phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/gnx-xgc)

Comment: Remove the quotes in your echo

Comment: It won't expand a value from a multi-dimensional array in a double-quoted string like that. You need either `echo "{$cars[1][1]}"` (curly brackets) or just drop the quotes altogether, since they aren't needed: `echo $cars[1][1]`. What it's actually doing there is the equivalent of `echo $cars[1] . "[1]"`

Comment: Ah, thanks!  Normal one-dimensional arrays work just fine in double-quoted strings, so it didn't occur to me it that that could be the problem.

Comment: w3schools is bad and you should feel bad...

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the way you're echoing the element.

```
echo $cars[1][1];    //60
```

You're using quotes around your variable:

```
echo "$cars[1][1]"; // Array[1]
```

You can include your array in a quoted string if you use curly braces:

```
echo "{$cars[1][1]}";    // 60
```